# Comparing nulls during join

Tags: mysql, join, natural-join

I read that null cannot be compared with null and the result is always false.

In the below link I am able to compare  2 nulls and the rows are returned.

```
CREATE TABLE user (id varchar(50), banstatus varchar(100));
INSERT INTO user (id, banstatus) VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO user values ('2', 'NULL');

CREATE TABLE banstatus (id varchar(50), texti varchar(100));
INSERT INTO banstatus VALUES('1', 'Banned');
Insert into banstatus values ('NULL' , 'NULL');

select * from user as u
join banstatus as b on u.banstatus=b.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33f25/1/0

So what is the correct statement about comparison of nulls ?

Comment: 'NULL' string (as you have) is not the same as NULL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f1cce/1/0  This fiddle shows only 1 record returned even though the 2nd is now 'NULL' not null string.  so to answer, "So what is the correct statement about comparison of nulls ?" what you've read.

Comment: Consider these case statements: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f1cce/7/1 `case when banstatus is null then 'Its Null' end as isNull,
case when banstatus = null then 'NULL = NULL' else 'NOT Null = Null' end as NullCantCompare,
case when banstatus  <> null then 'NULL <> Null' else 'NOT NULL <> NULL' end as NullNECompare,
case when banstatus  <=> null then 'NULL <=> Null' else 'NOT NULL <=> NULL' end as NULLSafeCompare`

Comment: Why is your ID value for users a `VARCHAR(50)`? That seems wrong. Normally you use an `INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` type to generate these numbers sequentially.

Comment: @tadman I was trying out different things with null values. Its just a random example and not from real db.

Comment: Do try and keep your examples as close to the situation you're trying to solve. Having really odd things in there distracts from the core problem and suggests you're just trying crazy things randomly, which is not a very effective way to solve problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you have inserted are strings. `'NULL'` is a string and is a definite value. To insert `NULL` you shouldn't use the quotes, for example:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES ('foo', NULL)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f7c0e/1)

And you can't compare with `NULL`, to understand its meaning it's something like undefined. Although, You can test if a value is or is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using  'NULL' (a string)   not NULL .. so you are comparing two (same ) strings

In mysql  there is  a null safe opearator that compare as true both null values

```
  <=>
```

NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

so for a correct null safe join you should use

```
 select * from user as u
 join banstatus as b on u.banstatus<=>b.id
```

Comment: He doesn't want to match them, he's wondering WHY they were being matched.

Comment: I am deleting this question otherwise I may receive downvotes for this silly question. I didn't notice that 'null' is a string.

Comment: answer  updated with the explain of your case and the solution for real null values ... and i don't see  downvote  .. your question seems  a correct (and not so rare) question

Answer (score 1):

In your answer you compare NULL as varchar, not plain NULL.